# ¿Cómo evitar el el salto de campo de formulario en un navegador con android al darle Sig.?

Tags: javascript

En una computadora con el con el código de abajo bloquea la tecla enter sin problema para que no salte de campo, pero desde un celular con android quisiera evitar que al presionar la tecla **Sig.** salte y no puedo conseguir que no salte al siguiente campo.

```
   <input type="text" name="post_tags" class="form-control form-control-md" data- 
   role="tagsinput" placeholder="Agregar" value="" required id="comainput" onkeypress="return 
   event.keyCode != 13;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que lo que quieres es que al pulsar tabulador, no enfoque al próximo input.

Para esto tienes que establecer la propiedad `tabindex` en -1, así podrás anular esta función.

### Ejemplo sin tabindex

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="usuario">
<input type="password" placeholder="contraseña">
<input type="text" placeholder="descripción">
<input type="submit">
<style>input{display: block;}</style>
```

### Ejemplo con tabindex -1

```html
<input type="text" tabindex="-1" placeholder="usuario">
<input type="password" tabindex="-1" placeholder="contraseña">
<input type="text" tabindex="-1" placeholder="descripción">
<input type="submit" tabindex="-1">
<style>input{display: block;}</style>
```